# Jquery ajax return value appending extra unwanted data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a php function from my $.ajax call to add a new item to the database.  The php function echos a comma separated list of values which I want to use in my ajax success function.
The problem is that the data from the ajax success function seems to have some extra, unwanted data appended to the front of the return string and I have no idea where this comes from!

Here's the php function:

```
function add_event_role()
{           
        //validated by jquery already
        $newID = $this->Event_model->insert_event_role(
            $this->input->post('roleEventType'),
            $this->input->post('roleName'),
            $this->input->post('roleRate'));

        //create return value for ajax of id,name of event type
        $retStr = $newID . ',' . $this->get_event_type_name($this->input->post('roleEventType'));

        log_message('error','retStr=' . $retStr);

        echo $retStr; //to send back to ajax call
        return $newID;
}
```

And here is the jquery that calls this:

```
   //set form data into a variable
        var dataString = 'roleEventType='+ typeId+'&roleName='+name+'&roleRate='+rate;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('settings/add_event_role'); ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                                    //split the return from add_event_role (it's: id,name)
                                    var splitArr = data.split(',');                                        
                        //message user 
                $.jGrowl("New event role added!", { header: 'Success' });
                //reload event roles to show new event role
                var newRow = "<tr><td>"+splitArr[1]+ "</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+rate+"</td><td><a href=\"edit\" id=\"" +splitArr[0]+"\"  class=\"editEventRole\">Edit</a> / <a href=\"delete\" id=\"" +splitArr[0]+"\"  class=\"deleteEventRole\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
                $("#eventRoleList").append(newRow);
                //clear add event form
                //...
            }

        });
```

As an example:  The php function ends up creating the string "12,role" and echos that.  By the time it reaches the success function it now reads:  "role12,role".  Anyone know why the name is being appended?  I have a feeling it's something really simple but right now I can't see it for looking at it so any help much appreciated! :)

UPDATE:

Thanks to help from Val & Jonathan Kuhn I tracked the problem back to a stray call to "echo" in the function: get_event_type_name which was appending the name onto the following echo.

Perhaps this question should be deleted as the error isn't truly related to Jquery/Ajax after all?

Comment: suspect it's one of these: echo $retStr; or return $newID; Comment out one and try it

Comment: Yep, tried both of those... but of course, I need echo $retStr to get the value back from the php function...

Comment: try to do a var_dump() of $retStr. Then you can see if the extra characters are apart of $retStr or being sent out somewhere else in the script.

Comment: var_dump shows the correct string in $retStr which suggests the extra data is being appended somewhere else.  Any ideas?

Comment: well on the comment it states that $retStr; outputs it for ajax to read as response, can you `var_dump($newID);` just before `echo $retStr` you should have something like `int(2)(12)` if you get something similar like `string(6)role12` then the problem is on your `$newID;`

Comment: Interesting, when I var_dump($newID) I get a string followed by int(35).  Using my example above: "roleint(35)".  All $newID is, is the return value after I insert a new row to my db table, the return value is: return $this->db->insert_id();   I'm using codeignitor.  I'll look into that! thanks

Comment: that means that your $newID is 35; which is an (int) the id of the database, which means your problem is not even here it's else where before this method...

Comment: Right, I've followed it back but still no luck.  $newID seems to be fine, and the value returned from inserting the new row is fine too.  I've no idea how this unwanted string could have been appended!  Unless there is something that happens between echo $retStr and my ajax success function receiving the data?

Comment: Ok, found it.  It was a stray echo higher up in the call stack.  Thanks Val for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from Val & Jonathan Kuhn I tracked the problem back to a stray call to "echo" in the function: get_event_type_name which was appending the name onto the following echo.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "echo" and "return" withing the same function. try removing the "return $newID;" statement you don't need it. it's probably what caused the extra text

Comment: how could a return output itself ?

Comment: Removing the return call makes no difference and should be fine anyway.